# How to change axis font in PrimeFaces and Chart.js

Tags: canvas, primefaces, jsf-2, chart.js

I am using PrimeFaces 7, and I am trying to use barchart from Chart.js as follows:

[image]

Code:

```html
<p:barChart  widgetVar="cfg" model="#{dashboardBean.barModel}" style="width:500px;height:348px;"/>
```

and I create my model as follows:

```java
private void createBarModel(Map<String, Double> delegatesMap) {
    barModel = new BarChartModel();
    barModel.setExtender("skinBar");
    // ...
}
```

I am trying to change the axis font family using extender function as follows:

```js
function skinBar() {
        var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.cfg.config);

    options = {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
                        fontSize:40
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
                        fontSize:40
                    }
                }]
            }
        }

       
       $.extend(true, this.cfg.config, options);
    }
```

but it's not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like you have everything right.  I tried it in this JSFiddle and it sets the FontFamily correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/0zxguLps/   So now we need to figure out why your Chart Extender functionality is not working.  Can you put a breakpoint in the Extender JavaScript and make sure its actually being called?

Comment: Hi Mahmoud. As per prior edits on your questions, the personal pronoun "I" in English always is a capital. Readers would rather it was written correctly, even if you're using a mobile device. With regret, I have downvoted this post constructively in the hope it will help you remember on future posts.

Comment: @halfer, thanks for your kind note, it's my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked by changing my extender function as follows.

Model:

```java
barModel = new BarChartModel();
barModel.setExtender("skinBar");
```

Extender function:

```js
function skinBar() {
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Tahoma';
}
```

reference: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can't, or don't want to use an extender function, you can add this to the bottom of your template (before `</body>`):

```html
<script>if(typeof Chart!=='undefined'){Chart.defaults.font.family='...'}</script>
```

It will apply if any charts are visible at the moment the page is rendered. So not perfect, and I suggest to use the extender instead when possible.